# Best way to validate database insertions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a process that consumes an export file and inserts the data into my database.

As part of the test process I created an SQL script for each insertion. So if the value exists, I would return the results, if it didn't I return no results. I would use a batch file to run all 1000 of my files and see the results.

Thinking about it a little more is there a better way to test this? I am imaging the case where all statements fail and a blank output is returned (which isnt too useful).

Is there a way I can do the inverse so that if the value does exist I return Null and if it doesn't I return what is in the database? I think this option would be more useful from a debug standpoint.

Open to other suggestions as well. My SQL statements I am using are very basic.

If it helps I am dealing with Oracle SQL

Comment: What about running some tests directly on the export file itself, before generating any SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does make a difference that you are using Oracle, what are you using as your client language? If you are just using Oracle and SQLPlus you can add error handling to your scripts - read the SQLPlus documentation to see how -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm

Otherwise you'll have to raise an exception in your client language and either log it or handle it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by client language. i am using VBA in combination with SQL. I wouldn't get any errors in my script, I would just get a null result since the value wouldn't exist in my DB

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for suggestions, here is mine:

Write a stored procedure to perform insert statements. Call the stored procedure from your client language (VBA code). Using a stored procedure will also provide some performance benefit, but that is secondary.

In my example, I have a stored proced that writes to the test_insert table. If the insert fails, it will write a record to the ti_logerrors table. You need to call the stored procedure from your VBA code.

*Example:* 
**Main Table:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq 
  START WITH 1000; 

CREATE TABLE test_insert 
  ( 
     tid   NUMBER(12, 2), 
     tdesc VARCHAR2(1000), 
     ttime DATE NOT NULL 
  );
```

**Logging Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE ti_logerrors 
  ( 
     logtime DATE, 
     logdesc VARCHAR2(4000) 
  )
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Proc_testinsert(tdesc IN VARCHAR2, 
                                            ttime IN DATE) 
IS 
  PRAGMA autonomous_transaction; 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO test_insert 
    VALUES     (my_seq.NEXTVAL, 
                tdesc, 
                ttime); 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
             INSERT INTO ti_logerrors 
             VALUES     (SYSDATE, 
                         Nvl(tdesc, 'NULL') 
                         || ' HAS FAILED. '); 

             COMMIT; 
END;
```

Comment: 'Using a stored procedure will also provide some performance benefit' - can you give some basis for that statement? Why is your procedure autonomous? And is this better than using the [built-in error logging table mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55097)?

Comment: The autonomous nature of the procedure is to log errors even if the insert fails and /or the transaction is being controlled by the client side VBA script.

Comment: The built-in features of the database are always the best way to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you suggest in PL/SQL would be easy and also possible in vb but essentially

```
declare
  cursor c_check_exists(p_pk number) is 
  select 'x'
  from table
  where table_id = p_pk;

  l_check_exists varchar2(1);
begin
  -- loop through all the things you want to check (look up pl/sql for loop)
  open c_check_exists(l_pk);
  fetch c_check_exists into l_check_exists;
  if c_check_exists%NOTFOUND then 
    -- doens't exist, run your process create a procedure for this
  else
    -- any logging you want to do e.g. dbms_output.put_line('l_pk: '||l_pk||' exists');
  end if;
end;
```

The guy above that says a stored procedure will be faster is sometimes true, you may eliminate network traffic as pl/sql executes on the server and can run sql very fast and may be more able to eliminate context switching - see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602